# how to increment any string [input] by +3 then output the resulting string in python

Tags: python, string, increment

I tried using asciii and tried ord() but I could not use the input of the user and increment it by 3 letters. For example I want to be able to have the following scenario:

input: abc
output: def

and also it would loop back from z to a so:

input: xyzab
output: abcde

these are just examples of input, the code should work on any input of letters.

its starting to be mind boggling for me.

for those who wonder this is just a challenge I encountered in the blackhat event last year in Riyadh and obviously couldn't beat.

Comment: You triend and failed? or is it the challenge to not convert to ascii? because with ASCII it's just a simple function I think.

Comment: @sahasrara62 when I tried to take the code from the question you mentioned it does not work on 3 for some reason. And it does not take any input.

Comment: "when I tried to take the code from the question you mentioned it does not work on 3 for some reason" Well, yes, because the other question said to increment by 1. There are many different answers there. For any one of them, you will probably notice that it says `1` in the code in at least one place. Did you try to **understand** how the code works? Perhaps, where the code says `1`, some or all of those should be changed to `3`. If you study the code, maybe you can figure out which ones. Otherwise, perhaps try some trial and error.

Comment: "And it does not take any input." - again, you will see how the code works on a string that was already assigned to some variable, and you will see how the code mentions some variable name. What if you try using the input, to assign to that variable (instead of whatever else is assigning it)? What if you try replacing the variable, with the code to get the input? The reason for closing questions as a duplicate is because questions here are supposed to be **single questions** about a **single problem**. We do not write the complete code for you.

Comment: Yes i did change the 1️⃣ to 3️⃣ of course! And yes thanks i just needed to get back into the art of writing code since i only learned in vb.net and now with python i was a little lost. Thanks for your trying to explain but rest assured the first thing i did was change the 1️⃣ to 3️⃣ lol

Answer (score 1):

you can use modulo arithmetic to handle the cases near the end

```py
def shift(text):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if (char.isupper()):
            result += chr((ord(char) + 3 - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + 3 - 97) % 26 + 97)
    return result

print(shift("ABC"))

print(shift("xyzab"))
```

Comment: ok thanks! I am going to try to tweak your code in order to make it does that to any input. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

for lower and upper english language alphabets, you can use below code

```
def func(string, increment=3):
    result = []
    orders = [65, 97]

    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        is_lower = char.islower()
        new_char = chr(orders[is_lower] + (ord(char)%orders[is_lower]+ increment)%26)
        result.append(new_char)

    return ''.join(result)


string = "xyzab"
result = "abcde"
assert result == func(string, 3)
```

Comment: the problem is I want to increment the input so it should work on any letters given by the input

Comment: @Kongming this work on any alphabet character lower and upper one

Comment: ok but where does this take the string from? it does not take an input like I put in the original problem.

Comment: @Kongming just use this as func("yourString")